# Обработать ответ сервера

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Как после отправки формы на сервер, сделать редирект на URL? И отменить переход на URL сервера, где отображается код ошибки и наоборот успешной отправки формы.

Код формы представлен ниже:

```js
function submitForm (oFormElement) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert (xhr.responseText); 
    }
    xhr.open (oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
    xhr.send (new FormData (oFormElement));
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form name = "sign" method="POST" action="http://someurl" onsubmit="submitForm(document.forms.sign);">
    <p class = "username">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
    </p>
    <p class = "username">
        <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Second Name" required="required" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
    </p>
    <p class = "email">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
    </p>
    <p class = "gender">
        <select name = "gender" required="required">
            <option value = "">Select your gender</option>
            <option value = "male">Male</option>
            <option value = "female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p class = "password">
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="required">
    </p>
    <p class = "checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id = "checker">
        <span>Conditions of Agreement</span>
    </p>
    <p class = "submit">
        <input type="submit" id = "sent" name = "Sent" disabled="true" >
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: *Отправку формы делал не на AJAX.* -- а придётся.

Comment: окей. сделаю на AJAX. я уже понял, что придется))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57824/discussion-on-question-by-vlad-teryoshin---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="sign" method="POST" action="http://someurl" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">


xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data);
  }
};
```

Comment: спасибо, а для чего парсить в json?

Comment: @VladTeryoshin У Вас же, кажется, в одной из предыдущих редакций вопроса был ответ показан в виде JSON. Если не надо - не парсите.

Comment: это ответы от сервера, это уже было, я их такими не делал.
спасибо, и если можно, еще вопрос: мне необходимо сделать при успешной регистрации редирект на другую страницу, могу я проверять  соответствие прям в функции отправки данных на сервер? или необходимо создать новую, где я буду сравнивать responseText успешным ответом сервера?

Comment: @VladTeryoshin так и так можно